# Slow Context New Submenu in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, context-menu

When you first open the right click menu and scroll to the New submenu there will be a long delay (2-5 seconds) before the submenu opens. Once the New submenu opens you can roll the mouse cursor on and off the submenu and it will close and re-open quickly, but as soon as you allow the Context menu to close and try the re-open it the problem returns.

is there a way to set a delay in ms for this item somehow? Or this could be a bug?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the behavior within a virtual machine with a fresh installation of the same version of Windows 10 on your system?  If you cannot, then it's unlikely a bug, but something on your system that is installed that is misbehaving.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this on 10.0.17763 with only 12 items in the "New" menu (not a fresh install).

Comment: I traced the problem up to *State Repository Service*. There is hi CPU, but not I/O during the submenu opening. I tried to re-register all Appx, reset Edge. Also tried to disable all programs which registered ShellNew (using ShellNewHandler.exe). The problem goes away if I stop the service. But that's no solution as it takes all Metro functionality too. e.g. There is no 'Start menu'. There is no clue in procmon. Hope someone could take this further.

Comment: And this is definitely a bug, as there doubtfully is a feature "freeze the Explorer for 10 secs to annoy the user" or any other setting which might do just that. It's unintentional and it's bothering other processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLVED IT FINALLY**

Solution is to remove some of the universal apps that are causing issues with one update.
Just open Power Shell and paste this into it:

```
Get-AppxPackage *zune* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *sketch* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *photos* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *wallet* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *solitai* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *bing* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *help* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *3d* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *reality* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *office* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

[image]

Once these apps are removed, wait a few seconds until you can see that the Windows taskbar flickers for a tiny moment. That is the sign that Windows's Explorer acknowledged these changes. Now you can try right clicking and select "New". Depending on the PC's processor speed, the delay is now either non-existent or at least greatly reduced. Side note: The first three apps in the lines above cause the longest delays.

See here for more [info](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/120135-desktop-new-context-menu-behaving-slow-after-upgrade-1809-a-3.html#post1624161).

Comment: Works! Here's some info from the forum post before it dissapears: "Once these apps are removed, wait a few seconds until you can see that the Windows taskbar flickers for a tiny moment. That is the sign that Windows's Explorer acknowledged these changes. Now you can try rightclicking and select "New". Depending on the PC's processor speed, the delay is now either non-existent or at least greatly reduced. Side note: The first three apps in the lines above cause the longest delays."

Comment: This is the right answer! FINALLY my `New` context menu doesn't take 5 seconds to load! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found a registry tweak to reduce the delay for submenu to pop up. Just open Registry Editor and browse to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`. By default, the **MenuShowDelay** value is set to 400 millisecond. You can change it to a lower number or even 0 to make the submenu pop up more quickly. Source: https://www.top-password.com/blog/how-to-speed-up-windows-10-menu-animations/

Comment: This is not a system defined delay and can last as long as 5 seconds

Comment: The delay is used by the system to adjust the speed for an animation effect for the submenu to pop up. It also works with Windows 7.

Comment: Not sure you understood the question. Once again - this is not a system defined delay as it can last as long as 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

A slow right-click is caused by context menu handlers. See here: http://windowsxp.mvps.org/slowrightclick.htm

This article will show you how to disable "context menu" handlers step-by-step. In so doing, you'll be able to see which handler would be caused slow menu.